# Evaluate all pairs of two meshgrids

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In 1-d I can easily and elegantly achieve what I want, but I'm unable to transfer it to 2-d or even higher dimensional

**1-d**

I have two 1-d meshes of size N = 3.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [10, 20, 30]
```

now I want to evaluate a function fun on on the difference/norm of all pairs of these meshes:

```
def fun(x):
    return x

mgrid = np.meshgrid( a,b )
A = fun( np.abs(mgrid[0] - mgrid[1] ) )
```

Result A is of size N x N:

```
array([[ 9,  8,  7],
       [19, 18, 17],
       [29, 28, 27]])
```

which is

```
|b[0]-a[0]| |b[0]-a[1]| |b[0]-a[2]|
|b[1]-a[0]| |b[1]-a[1]| |b[1]-a[2]|
|b[2]-a[0]| |b[2]-a[1]| |b[2]-a[2]|
```

(only arguments of fun, for sake of brevity)

**2-d**

Now in 2-d function fun stays the same.

I have again two meshes a and b

```
ax = [1, 2, 3]
ay = [4, 5, 6]
bx = [10, 20, 30]
by = [40, 50, 60]

a = np.meshgrid(ax, ay)
b = np.meshgrid(bx, by)
```

Now, how can I do the same I did with the 1-d meshes above for 2-d and possibly also for higher dimensions?

The first line of A:

```
|| (10 40) - (1 4) || || (10 40) - (1 5) || || (10 40) - (1 6) ||
|| (10 40) - (2 4) || || (10 40) - (2 5) || || (10 40) - (2 6) ||
|| (10 40) - (3 4) || || (10 40) - (3 5) || || (10 40) - (3 6) ||
```

(everything in one line, again only arguments of fun)

The result mesh should have the size N * N x N * N.

I tried to create the coordinates of a and b

```
ca = np.array(list(zip(a[0].flatten(), a[1].flatten())))
cb = np.array(list(zip(b[0].flatten(), b[1].flatten())))
```

And create a meshgrid from that:

```
mgrid = np.meshgrid([ca], [cb])
```

but alone the dimensionality does not fit (18 instead of 9).

EDIT: Completely reworked the question.

Comment: How about flatten the inputs to 1D and then feed those to meshgrid?

Comment: If `f()` takes two 1D vectors, how does `f( np.abs(mgrid[0] - mgrid[1]) )` give useful output?  That's a 2D input.

Comment: Also if you can't tell us what `f()` is directly please at least be clearer about what inputs and outputs are what shape and what type (`array`, `tuple` or `list`), as your variable names change constantly and your notations are not clear.  A [mcve] in this case would gave clear input (type, number and shape), clear expected output (type, number and shape) with some sample of what output is expected from a given "toy" input.  I'm sure all that is in there somewhere, it's just really hard to find right now.

Comment: I reworked my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be accomplished using `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`.

```
def fun(x):
    return x

ax = [1, 2, 3]
ay = [4, 5, 6]
bx = [10, 20, 30]
by = [40, 50, 60]

a = np.meshgrid(ax, ay)
b = np.meshgrid(bx, by)
ca = np.vstack(a).reshape(2, -1).T
cb = np.vstack(b).reshape(2, -1).T
A = scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(ca, cb)
A = fun(A)
```

A is of shape (9,9)